# make 3d and 2d equation

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, linear-regression

I study linear-regression with the following MIT course:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7DzL2_Na80&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8&index=2

at 20:52 I want to make a 3D image with Python. And I get the following error message:

> 'ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping'

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()


ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

z = np.array([[0],[-1.],[4]])
x = np.array([[2.],
              [-1.]
              [0]])
y = np.array([[-1.],[2.],[-3.]])
ax.plot(x, y, z,  label='linear')
ax.legend()

A=np.array([[2.,-1.,0.],
            [-1.,2.,-1.],
            [0.,-3.,4.]])
b=np.array([[0.],
            [-1.],
            [4.]])



plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of you only want to make a 3D scatter plot, here is example code using your data.

[image: scatterplot]

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([2., -1., 0], dtype=float) # dtype ensures floating point numbers
yData = numpy.array([-1.,2.,-3.], dtype=float)
zData = numpy.array([0, -1., 4], dtype=float)

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems



if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    ScatterPlot(data)
```

Comment: Actually i want make 3equation about 2x-y=0, -x+2+-z=-1,-3y+4z=4  by mathplotlib

Comment: If you can provide an equation of the form "z = f(x,y)" I can provide example Python surface fitting code with 3D scatterplot, 3D surface plot, contour plot, and fit statistics of RMSE and R-squared and then add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much james . Please give me 3D scatterplot about (2x-y =0 ,-x+2y-z =-1, -3y+4z=4 ) with 3 coordinates (xyz).

Comment: This is not in the form "z = f(x,y)" as I requested.